# ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

Tags: c

I am trying to run this code on my local machine, but I am receiving the following errors:

> ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings] error in my Terminal

> File is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.

These erros are blocking me compiling the code, I am using **C | Visual Studio Code | Windows 10 and MSY2 Ming64w** to compile my code - can you help me solve this?

my.functions.h

```
#ifndef HW1

#define HW1

#include <stdio.h>

int str_length(char*);
void str_copy(char* src, char* dest);
int str_find(char* src, char* dest);
int get_unnamed_argument(int index, int argc, char **argv, char *result);
int get_named_argument(int index, int argc, char **argv, char *result);

#endif
```

my_fuctions.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "my_functions.h"

int str_length(char* string) {

    int c = 0;

    for (c = 0; string[c] != '\0'; c++);
    return c;
}

void str_copy(char* d, char* source) 
{
    int i;
    
    for (i = 0; source[i] != '\0'; i++) 
    {
        d[i] = source[i];
    }

    d[i] = '\0';
}


int str_find(char* needle, char* haystack)

{
    int c,x;

    for(c = 0; c < str_length(haystack); c++){
        if (needle[0] == haystack[c]){
            int count = 0;
            for(x = 0; x < str_length(needle); x++){
                if(needle[x] == haystack[c+x]){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == str_length(needle)){
                return c;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int get_unnamed_argument(int index, int argc, char **argv, char *result) {

    int c;

    for (c = 0;c <= index;c++) {

        if (index > argc - 1) {

            return -1;

        }

        else if (str_find("=",argv[c]) != -1) {

            index++;

        }

        else if (str_find("--",argv[c]) != -1) {

            return -1;

        }

        else if (c == index) {

            str_copy(result,argv[c]);

            return str_length(argv[c]);

        }

    }

    return -1;
}

int get_named_argument(int index, int argc, char **argv, char *result) {

    int c;

    for (c = 0; c <= index; c++) {

        if (index > argc - 1) {

            return -1;

        }
        
        else if (str_find("=",argv[c]) == -1) {

            index++;

        }
        
        else if (str_find("--",argv[c]) != -1) {

            return -1;

        }
        
        else if (c == index) {

            str_copy(result, argv[c]);

            return str_length(argv[c]);

        }
    }
    
    return -1;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "my_functions.c"

#include "my_functions.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char t[1];
    int counter;
    scanf("%s %i", t, &counter);
    if (str_length(t) == 1 && str_find("n", t) != -1) 
    {
        if (counter <= 0) 
        {
            counter = argc;
        }
        int c;
        for (c = 0; c < counter; c++) 
        {
            char result[255];
            int arg_len = get_named_argument(c, argc, argv, result);
            if (arg_len == -1) 
            {
                return 0;
            }
            printf("%s\n", result);
        }
    } else if (str_length(t) == 1 && str_find("u", t) != -1)
    {
        if (counter <= 0) 
        {
            counter = argc;
        }
        int c;
        for (c = 0; c < counter; c++) 
        {
            char result[255];
            int arg_len = get_unnamed_argument(c, argc, argv, result);
            if (arg_len == -1) 
            {
                return 0;
            }
            printf("%s\n", result);
        }
    } else {
        if (counter <= 0) 
        {
            counter = argc;
        }
        int c;
        for (c = 0; c < counter; c++) {
            if (str_find("--", argv[c]) != -1) 
            {
                return 0;
            }
            printf("%s\n", argv[c]);
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: "I am using C | Visual Studio Code" No, you are not. The error message you get is specific for C++, not C. You must use a C++ compiler to get that error

Comment: Please add the command line that is executed for building your program to the question

Comment: To build / run this code I use the GCC command

Comment: On an unrelated note: `scanf("%s %i", t, &counter);` will lead to *undefined behavior*. The format `%s` will write a ***null-terminated** string* into `t`. But since `t` only have space for a single character, there's no place for the null-terminator. Which in turn means that `scanf` will write out of bounds of the array `t`, leading to said undefined behavior.

Comment: What is "the GCC command"? Gcc is a program that requires quite some arguments to compile your code. Please add the complete and exact command line to the question.

Comment: Other than that, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the *minimal* part. And learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: Furthermore, don't `#include` source files. That's not the correct way to handle multi-source projects. Build each source file separately into an object file, then link all object files together into the executable program.

Comment: The problem here is that you haven't gotten your programming environment set up correctly. You are compiling with a C++ compiler and you aren't using a proper project for your IDE. The IDE should handle which .c files that are linked.

Comment: Add `-std=c99` to `gcc` command and follow suggestions above to correctly setup your project.